# how to use elasticsearch with langchain

Tags: python, elasticsearch, langchain

I want to use elasticsearch with the langchain, i have gone thru the documentation but in the documentation they create a text file which is appended in elasticsearch and than you can query it.
basically i want to perform RAG. I need to query the data already existing in the elasticsearch at some index

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
# Connect to Elasticsearch cluster
es = Elasticsearch(['http://10.100.102.107:9200'])
# Define your query
query = {
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}  # Match all documents
    }
}
# Execute the query
result = es.search(index="instagram_index", body=query)
# Process the results
for hit in result['hits']['hits']:
    print(hit['_source'])
```

this is the code where it returns dummy data of some accounts, consisting of username, text etc

i want to query this data through lanngchain
i am relatively new to this field and i know there is a lot to learn but i need guidance regarding this.